# How to send query parameters from one web application to another?

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, web-applications, query-string

I have a requirement wherein I have to redirect to a page of another web application and send information through query string.

Below is sample code for **WEB-APP 1**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/WebApp2/default.htm?name=Akshay&surname=lokur">
            <input type="submit" value="click me!">

        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

When user clicks Submit button, default.htm (which is in another web application) should open up and should receive query parameters viz. "name" and "surname".

Currently, default.html opens up but it does not receive any of the sent query parameters!

Comment: You are referring to `default.htm`, not `default.html`. Additionally, opening a URL with query parameters does not "lose" them on the way. Without any further explanations, we cannot help you.

Comment: yes, strange but I am not getting any query params in another web application's default.htm though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to display the request parameters within your html then you can do

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/WebApp2/default.jsp?name=Akshay&surname=lokur">
            <input type="submit" value="click me!">

        </form>
        <div><%=(request.getParameter("name")!=null?request.getParameter("name"):"")%></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**What is going on?**

- `<%` & `%>` are tags for java scriplets.
- > (condition?statement if true:statement if false)

  is a [ternary
  if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java) which is similar to:

> ```
> if(<condition>){
>    statement if true;
> }else{
>    statement if false;
> }
> ```

- So, the above added code `(request.getParameter("name")!=null?request.getParameter("name"):"")` becomes similar to:

> ```
> if(request.getParameter("name")!=null){
>    request.getParameter("name");
> }else{
>    "";
> }
> ```

- Finally,

> **=**

is just to display the conditional result right there

I hope that helped you.

Edit: Just noticed you are not using jsp(Why? Given that you want to display posted data). Changed my version to jsp as that's the only way we can display request parameters in html.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work to me.  What makes you think the parameters are not sent?  I suggest loading your page in Firefox with Firebug installed, then click on Firebug and view the network tab.  Then click your submit button and you will be able to see in the network panel the parameters that were sent.  If you can verify that that parameters were sent than maybe the way you are checking for them on the other server is not working.